# Coffeescript/jQuery Pattern: Caching Data Across Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a list of items that are abstracts, and can be made to expand via Ajax on click. I'v written the following code in Coffeescript:

```
current_open_row = null

$('li.faq-item').live 'click', (event) ->
  $.post("/faqs/update_rows", {old_row_id: current_open_row, new_row_id: $(this).attr('id')}, (data) ->
    replace_items data
  , 'json')
  current_open_row = $(this).attr('id')
```

This doesn't read like smooth Coffeescript and I find myself thinking, "what could I have done better," but in particular, instantiating the `current_open_row` variable outside the scope of the click handler feels strange. Not doing this, of course, causes a new instantiation upon entry to the handler, which is always undefined.

Other than refactoring `$(this).attr('id')` into a variable, is there anything that jumps out as ugly, suboptimal, unreadable, etc., or is this pretty much the way of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off, I think you'll find yourself switching to camelCase eventually... I know that many people strongly prefer the readability_of_underscores, but every library you interact with (including jQuery) uses camelCase. Just something to keep in mind.

Setting that aside, the issue of having to scope variables with `= null` is a good one. I've tried to persuade Jeremy that there should be a nicer scoping syntax, but he's firmly against it. So I'd suggest moving the variable to an object property. Fortunately, this is jQuery, so there are plenty of places to stick data. How about using the list's [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method? This has an additional advantage: If you want to do this on multiple lists in the future (with one `current_open_row` in each list), you won't have to change your code one bit. Just add more lists with `.faq-item` children to the markup.

One more minor point: You give the `post` call a callback

```
(data) -> replace_items data
```

If that's all you're doing, why not just pass `replace_items` directly? :)

I'd also put each argument to the `post` function on its own line for readability. Key-value pairs are automatically combined into a single object, even without curly braces. Here's how it all looks:

```
$('li.faq-item').live 'click', (event) ->
  $row = $(this)
  $list = $row.parent()
  row_id = $row.attr 'id'

  $.post(
    "/faqs/update_rows",
    old_row_id: $list.data('current_open_row'),
    new_row_id: row_id,
    replace_items,
    'json'
  )

  $list.data 'current_open_row', row_id
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helps. I believe snakeCase is fine in Javascript but a greater portion of my code is Ruby and staying with the Ruby convention makes a ton of sense even though jQuery uses snakeCase. Scoping variables is difficult in all dynamic languages and is often surprising in behavior. This just felt so hacky, though, that I had to post the question.